# Codeigniter using Model View and Controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

What will be the process to show to data in codeignator using Model View and Controller?

**Controller**

```
public function SecondarySchoolLevel() {
    $this->load->model('Schoolprogram_model');
    $data['progcategoryid'] = $this->Schoolprogram_model->getschoolprog(4);

    $this->load->view('SchoolPrograms', $data);
}
```

**View**

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * from programs where progcategoryid = $progcategoryid");

foreach ($query->result_array() as $row){
?>
<tr id="r<?php echo $row["progid"]; ?>">
<td><?php echo $row["progcode"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["activities"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["description"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["session"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["hours"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["cost"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["progcategoryid"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["agefrom"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["ageto"]; ?></td>
```

**Model**

```
function getschoolprog($progcategoryid) {
    $this->db->where('progcategoryid', $progcategoryid);
    $query = $this->db->get('programs');
    return $query->result();
}
```

This is my code.

Comment: you want to show your query result in your codeignter views

Comment: Yes....if u have any idea. please let me know.

Comment: You are executing query in view. This is not correct as per the MVC. The query should be executed in model.

Comment: First have a look at [mvc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Controller**

```
public function SecondarySchoolLevel() {
    $this->load->model('Schoolprogram_model');
    $data['progcategoryid'] = $this->Schoolprogram_model->getschoolprog(4);//result of your query is stored in this ($data['progcategoryid']) variable
    $this->load->view('SchoolPrograms', $data);
}
```

**Model**

```
function getschoolprog($progcategoryid) {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->where('progcategoryid', $progcategoryid);
    $query = $this->db->get('programs');
    return $query->result_array();//<---- returns you an array
}
```

**View**

```
foreach ($progcategoryid as $key => $row) { ?>
    <tr id='r<?php echo $row["progid"]; ?>'>
        <td><?php echo $row["progcode"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["activities"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["description"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["session"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["hours"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["cost"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["progcategoryid"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["agefrom"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["ageto"]; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Controller**

```
 $data['progcategoryid'] = $this->Schoolprogram_model->getschoolprog(4);
 $this->load->view('SchoolPrograms', $data);
```

**View**

```
<?php foreach($progcategoryid as $row)
{
?>
 <td><?php echo $row->progcode; ?></td>// you can render your data like this

<?php }?>
```

> No need to write query in `view` because you've already  written it
>   within your `model`.

You just need to send your data to `views`